# Return html response from PHP page in to variable

Tags: php, html, email, include

I am trying to generate an email with some HTML that is created via another PHP file.

Email generating file is run by a cron running every hour.
Another file exists that generates the HTML required for the email.

The HTML generating file does not have a function that I can call, for instance:

```
$emailBody = generateHTML($id);
```

The HTML generating file was designed to be included on a page that you wished to display the HTML, for instance:

```
include "htmlGenerator.php";
```

My question is: How can I get what the htmlgenerator.php file returns in to a variable, ready to be pushed in to an email.

Apologies if this is not very clear, I will be happy to answer any questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just use $emailBody. Include behaves as though the included files contents where pasted into the context it's included in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood what you said, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php),
so that you can get the output of `htmlGenerator.php`

For example:

```
ob_start();
// as an example
echo "Hello World";
// or in our case
include "htmlGenerator.php";
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

You can also create a simple function like this:

```
function include_output($filename)
{
    ob_start();
    include $filename;
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
}

$mycontent = include_output("htmlGenerator.php");
```

Read the php documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the built-in functions ob_start and ob_get_clean.

You can then do something like:

```
ob_start();
include( "file.php");
$var = ob_get_clean();
```